# How to provide ignite-cofig xml for Driver Manager?

Tags: java, ignite, gridgain

If you access this URL -> https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jdbc-driver#section-streaming-mode

There it is mentioned that we can use streaming mode using cfg connection that has to be provided using ignite-jdbc.xml file.

But what are the contents of that file? How do we configure?

Answer (score 0):

As that same page notes, it's "a complete Spring XML configuration." Have a look in the "examples" directory of the Ignite download for some samples, but the important thing is how to find the rest of the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that preferred option for streaming with JDBC is using thin client driver (which neither needs an XML nor starts a client node) together with [`SET STREAMING ON`](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/set).